# Fetching blocks of data from a huge file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix

There is a huge file mask.txt containing floating point numbers arranged in column format(single column of approx 2 million numbers)  I want to extract the data in blocks of 512*512. How do I fetch the next block of data. I have done the following but it is erroneous.

```
rawData=dlmread('mask.txt');
a1=reshape(rawData(1:262144),512,512);


a2=reshape(rawData(262145:524289),512,512);
```

What to do? Please resolve the problem. Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method is correct, it's simply your numbers that's wrong. You did the classical mistake of not counting the first number. The vector should be from [n:n+512^2-1], not [n:n+512^2] as you did. So to fix it, just do

```
a2=reshape(rawData(262145:524288),512,512);
```